# Angular application login with AD FS and Saml without any third party like auth0, OpenId Connect etc

Tags: angular, spring, saml, adfs

Business Requirement:  Spring Boot, Angular 8, AD FS Login With Saml.

Currently we are trying to develop an application that need to login with AD FS and protocol is saml.

I am not clear about the process flow how AD FS and Saml will work without any third party support.

Should i need any third party support like OpenId connect, auth0 for this login purpose?

Any library for angular that can help me to login with AD FS?

Thanks In Advance

Comment: Any solution you got? how you approched?

Answer (score 1):

Basically, this can't be done without an add-on.

You could add a [SAML stack](https://medium.com/the-new-control-plane/i-need-a-saml-stack-now-63d9691e2d43) on the client-side.

Node / passport could work here.

This means your app. will talk directly to ADFS via SAML.

You could also connect your app. to something like Auth0 (an IDP). Auth0 is then federated with ADFS.

Here your app. would talk OIDC to Auth0 and Auth0 would talk SAML to ADFS.

Why SAML?

OIDC is much simpler.

If you have ADFS on Server 2019. you could use the Angular MSAL library.

Your app. would then talk OIDC direct to ADFS.

Comment: Actually SAML is business requirement from my client.